# Find maximum number of dots that can be distributed on a rectangle when dimensions, distance are given

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

When a rectangle's width and length are W and L.
Find maximum number of dots that can be distributed on the rectangle.
Each dots must be apart D distance from each other.
The dots can be put on the sides of the rectangle.

For example, a rectangle's width and length are 8.
The distance that dots need to be apart from each other is $\sqrt8$.
How many dots can be put in the rectangle?
This question made me want to know how it can be generalized by changing the rectangle's width, length and the distance between dots to variables.
I got this problem from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-mxYrCNX60.

I tried to solve it by myself for a few hours but I couldn't think of a good way. I would be glad if you let me know how to solve it or related stuff to help solve this problem.

Comment: Packing problems are hard.  You are essentially packing circles into a square, but need to expand the squaree to allow for the part of the circle that extends outside your square, which is $D$ in each direction.  You can look at packomania.com to see how irregular the packings become.  Eight in a square has a nice regular configuration, but $7, 10, 11$ are not.

Comment: @RossMillikan Would irregular mean that there isn't a formular for finding how many dots can be put in a rectangle with given variables? I checked the website. Would it be the same even if the dots can be put on the sides of the square too? Thank you!

Comment: Allowing dots on the sides of the square is the same as the circles on the website if you expand the square by the radius of the circles on each side.  The reason this is hard is that there are many configurations of the dots and you are never sure you have the best one.  For small numbers of dots we can prove it, but for larger numbers they just scatter dots in the square and iteratively improve it until it converges, then try lots of times and hope one of them is the best configuration.

Comment: This might help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing